# Teams Email of connected user into message extension teams, message extension continue after login

Tags: authentication, search, openid, microsoft-teams, imessage-extension

I've one trouble with my teams custom app. I'm making a custom app that return sign-in action to unlogged user when he try to use a search message extension. Now, my problem is:

- How can I resume the query after the user logged?

I return to the user an auth composeExtension type that point to one route of my spa. The user make authentication and correctly return the accesstoken, but then it doesn't continue the search. I've already try call :

- microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess({ accesToken: oResponse.accessToken })

but it only close the opened popUp.
Please, help me. Thanks.

Comment: Let me take this question to internal team, and we will get back to you soon

Comment: Sorry, for late reply on this question. Please refer [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config) sample for auth in messaging extension and it clearly uses your scenario.

Comment: OK, I'll try, thanks for everything.